# New to JavaScript, how to do a null check?

Tags: javascript, null

I am trying to learn JavaScript. First day! I want to concatenate the First and Last names. This is what I have so far. It works fine, but if I don't enter one of the fields, it just shows up as `null`. How do I avoid that? Where would I put that clause in the following code? Thanks for your help in advance!

```
function ShowFullName()
{
    var varFirstName = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("lauren_firstname").getValue();
    var varLastName = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("lauren_lastname").getValue();
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("lauren_name").setValue(varFirstName + " "  + varLastName);
};
```

Comment: Part of learning JScript (or anything) will be learning to use the documentation.  Of course, you're welcome to ask questions here, but be aware that you are expected to show research effort.

Comment: By the way, what library are you using? Or, is "JScript" actually not a spelling error?

Comment: Any recommendations for a new person like me on where to start. I've been thrust into this world, and I'm reading online and trying to understand using JavaScript as best that I can. I need like a beginner's guide. Any suggestions? I currently am trying to use it within Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011.

Comment: @Lauren: Google "Douglas Crockford" and watch his lectures on YouTube.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that [all variables are *truthy* or *falsy*](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) in JavaScript.  In other words, every variable can be coerced (converted) into `true` or `false`.

`null` is *falsy*, and strings with content are *truthy*. That means:

```
var a = null;
var b = 'hello';

if (a) {
    // does not run
} else {
    // runs
}

if (b) {
    // runs
}
```

You can use other kinds of expressions too, like a [ternary expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) or the [logical OR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_%28.7C.7C%29):

```
alert(a ? 'yes' : 'no'); // => no
alert(b ? 'yes' : 'no'); // => yes

alert(a || b); // => hello
```

In this case, logical OR is our most interesting choice.  When you use the operator, the following happens:

1. If the left side evaluates *truthy*, return that value.
2. Otherwise, return the value that the right side evalutes to.

In the above example, `a` is `null`, so it is *falsy*.  The expression returns the right side, the value of `b`.  So we can take advantage of this behavior by writing `varFirstName || ''`, which will either return the first name (if there is one), or if it's null, the right side gives us an empty string.

```
function ShowFullName() {
    var varFirstName = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("lauren_firstname").getValue();
    var varLastName = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("lauren_lastname").getValue();

    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("lauren_name").setValue(((varFirstName || '') + " " + (varLastName || '')).trim());
}
```

I added a call to [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) to remove extra spaces from the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if something is null like:

```
if (obj == null) { 
  // do this
```

}

so something like

```
if (varFirstName == null) { varFirstname = "";}
```

This will set firstName to an empty string

Comment: Hi Darren, I added what you suggested right below my two var statements. I added this: if (varFirstName == null) { varFirstname = "";} 
if (varLastName == null) { varLastname = "";}

Comment: Sorry, i hit enter too fast. I typed in First Name, Lauren, and then it still says "null" so in my full name box it says Lauren Null......What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is it returning Null as in capital letter N ? If so, then it looks like a string "Null" is being returned as a null object is spelt all lowercase. Use this instead:
if (varLastName == null || varLastName == "Null") { varLastName = "";} - the || means 'Or'

Comment: You could also try checking for undefined. Use: if (varLastName is undefined){varLastName = "";}

Comment: Darren, thank you for youe help. I took Jeff's advice above and that worked just fine, and now I see you suggested the same thing. THank you so much for your help I really appreciate it.

Comment: No worries, glad it's all working now :) May I recommend you mark whomevers you want as the answer? it keeps your answer rate up and people will be more willing to help in the future. The same goes for clicking the up arrow on any answers you find helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
function ShowFullName()
    var varFirstName = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("lauren_firstname").getValue();
    var varLastName = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("lauren_lastname").getValue();

    if(varFirstName == null || varFirstName.ToLower() == "null") { 
        varFirstName = "";
    }

    if(varLastName == null || varLastName.ToLower() == "null") { 
        varLastName = "";
    }

    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("lauren_name").setValue(varFirstName + " "  + varLastName);
};
```

Comment: Jeff! Thank you so much for your help I really appreicate it. This worked great! Any recommendations for a new person like me on where to start. I've been thrust into this world, and I'm reading online and trying to understand as best that I can. I need like a beginner's guide. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry @Lauren I don't know much about JScript, it just happened that i know Xrm.Page.getAttribute will provides direct access to the Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get method.

Comment: Are the `.ToLower()` bits really necessary? If it's not `null`, could it become `null` after `.ToLower()`? (I know nothing about xrm, but I do know js...)

Comment: yes it is necessary because it will return String 'Null'. and just to make it more safe, that is why I added .ToLower()